# Avoid calling function twice in scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, storage, evaluation, persistent

I want to solve an optimization problem with scipy.optimize.minimize where both the objective and the inequality constraint function use the result of a common "simulation" function which depends on x.

The naive approach is simply to call the "simulation" function in the objective and the constraint. While this works, it is not very efficient because this means that "simulation" is evaluated twice.

Is there a way to avoid this, possibly by storing and reusing already computed results? In Matlab it is possible using a nested function ([see here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/objective-and-nonlinear-constraints-in-the-same-function.html)), however this did not seem to work in python.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You could have the shared function memoize its results.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a decision variable and an equality constraint:

```
  Min y
  y >= c
  y = fsimulation(x)
```

Of course, this generalizes to more-dimensional `y`.